# How to get scholars and scribes to write something?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm attempting to try the new writing system in Dwarf fortress, I have now for about 2 years had 2 scribes and about 6 scholars. They have access to about 10 empty scrolls and 10 empty quires. They also have 8 tables and chairs in the library and 2 of the scholars and one of the scribes is dedicated (no other jobs). The dedicated scribe is a proficient (very rusty) writer and the scholars have a variety of proficiency levels in various scholarly topics.

However, thus far they have failed to write a single scroll, produce a single book or even write on a single quire. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[Scholars](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Scholar) ponder, discuss and research, and write new works. [Scribes](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Scribe) only copy existing works. You'll probably want to focus on scholars more initially, since the scribes can't do any copying until there's something to copy.

[This](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=154895.0) forum post has some good experimental findings on scholars and scribes.

- Scholars seem to use the `Writer` skill to create new works.
- Scribes seem to use the `Reader` or `Student` skill, rather than `Writer` or `Wordsmith`, as you might expect.
- A typical scholar will only write a book every other season.
- Allowing everyone entrance to the library lets visiting scholars enter, who may write things for you.

Based on this guy's findings, I would suggest you make sure your scholars are as proficient in the `Writer` skill as possible. Make sure your library is open to visitors and they might write something (which your scribes could then copy).